# Unserialize not running on production server, works on localhost

Tags: php, serialization

I'm passing serialized data through query string

```
$msg = $nos.' of '.$recordsExtracted.' records imported';
header('Location: ../import-to-master.php?msg='.serialize($msg));
```

I'm using the below to capture the data

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
    $msg=unserialize($_GET['msg']);
}
```

On localhost, on echoing `$msg` the message is getting displayed on the screen.

But on the production server, though the message is visible in the url

```
import-to-master.php?msg=s:23:"5 of 5 records imported";
```

echoing `$msg` does not display anything. To make sure `$msg` is being processed, I appended it with a string like

```
$msg .= 'sdage';
```

and on refreshing the page, I got to see `sdage` on the page. So this means `unserialize` is not working on the server.

My first thought was maybe the production server's PHP version did not support `unserialize`, but the version is 5.2 which does support `serialize` and `unserialize`

I'm left to wonder what the problem might be.

**PS :** Yes, I've not taken care of escaping the data, but my priority right now is to solve the current issue and then go for getting safe input from the query string.

Comment: Try `urlencode` your data

Comment: Won't there be a problem with using `urlencode` and `serialize` at the same time?

Comment: Nope, you are encoding it for the URL. After using GET its just like regular data

Comment: Your local server and production servers have different php.ini settings (like magic quotes) - hence the different behaviour. You can check it by `var_dump($_GET['msg'])`

Comment: As a "rule of thumb" if passing data via URLs, use `urlencode`, if storing complex values (like Arrays) in the database/session/memcache/etc. use `serialize`. :)   Also what @MaxYakimets said.

Comment: Yes, the reason I'm using `serialize` is because in some cases, I'm passing an array through the query string. So it is a must and I can't drop using `serialize'

Comment: Also if you pass arbitrary objects via HTTP requests, you can base64 encode the string you get after serializing them. And base64 decode them, then deserialize them on receive. It just looks more clear to me, though unreadable)

Comment: var_dump($msg) is giving me `bool(false)`

Comment: You can use `json_encode` instead of serialize, it's more compact and readable. If you are redirecting to page an the same server, why not  using sessions?

Comment: @asprin , reread my comment, I did not say `var_dump($msg)`

Comment: If you want to use array in query string you can use `http_build_query()` to create query string. Data will be escaped for you. for example: `http_build_query([ 'a' => [1 => ['a', 'b'],2 => 'b',3 => 'c']]);` and in script you will get `var_dump($_GET):` => `array(1) {["a"]=>array(3) { [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b"} [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c"}}`

Comment: @asprin  You will have problems with using `urlencode` and transmitting serialized data via $_GET

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions. As it turns out, using `stripslahses` solved the issue and as pointed out by @MaxYakimets, magic quotes is indeed enabled on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a series of trial and errors, I solved it using

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
    $msg=unserialize(stripslashes($_GET['msg']));
}
```